# Yammer Embedded Feeds Error-This content cannot be displayed in a frame

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I had integrated Yammer Feed on my SharePoint Page but showing error in some browser as follows:

This content cannot be displayed in a frame

To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Answer (score 1):

Try to  add below urls to trusted sites IE:

https://*.yammer.com

https://*.assets-yammer.com

http://*Your sharepoint site url*

more details on IE trusted site refer : https://developer.yammer.com/upgrading-to-the-new-yammer-js-sdk/

if you are using SharePoint online then below urls:

https://*.yammer.com

https://*.assets-yammer.com

https://*.sharepoint.com

https://login.microsoftonline.com

Pointer is to check IE Trusted site setting.